# Jquery Count words in parsed XML file

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to be able to count the words within a parsed XML file. i thought i could use the code

```
'<span class="detail">' + $(play).find(" ").size() + '</span><span> Words</span></br>' +
```

to count the spaces that will tell me the amount of word but it will not count or run the statement.

what way can count the word from a parsed XML file

Comment: What does `play` contain? The whole XML file? A string?

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your page? Also you will probably want to use .length instead of size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to count the words in a String.

You could for example split the String on whitespaces and then count the array length like:

```
var sentence = 'I am a demo sentence.';
var numWords = sentence.split(' ').length; //should return 5
```

See the MDN page for **[String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**

Considering the markup in your question you could use an approach like **[in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fAMYR/2/)**